# Microsoft Teams, get current users in a call

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am creating a Bot for Microsoft Teams and I want to get the current users in a call. If you have a group or a team, maybe not all users in that group or team are currently participating in that call. I have managed to get all users in a group or team thanks to Microsoft.Bot.Builder 4.0 and Microsoft.Graph. But that is not what I want. Just the current active users in a call. I hope I have made my question clear enough. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look into the beta API for [List of Participants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/participant-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http).